# Can get Facebook posts but not status message

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to get a user status messages using the Facebook graph API. I have created an APP and with the help of APP ID/APP Secret code, I can get the access token and then get the posts by the user successfully with the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERID?fields=posts&access_token=XXX
```

But, I can not get the status message of the user. I am trying following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/statuses?access_token=XXX
```

I get the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 102
   }
}
```

How can I get the status message of the user? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read out the error message clearly:

It says you are not passing the access_token properly.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/**UserID**/statuses?access_token=**PASS_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE**
```

I hope your token have 'user_status' and 'friend_status' permissions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but as I mentioned above, with the same access key I can get the user posts, so there shoult not be any problem with that. Can you tell how can I set the user_status and friend_status permissions?

Comment: open this page https://developers.facebook.com/apps, You will see your application in the listing on the left on above mentioned URL, Go to 'Edit Settings', On the left side of your screen, you will see a few options - Basic, Permissions, Advanced etc, Click on 'Permissions' It will open up a page, enter 'user_status', 'friend_status' in the right side white text Area/box. Hit the 'save changes'  button and regenerate the token by logging again and then fetch statuses etc Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but still no success, same message. :(

Comment: It must be about generating the token again. You need to regenerate it. For Eg: You can use this kinda token for testing purpose which will expire in a couple of hours. You need to regenerate the token in order to have access to the data. For testing purpose: You can open this URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fstatuses and Click on 'Get Access Token' it will open up a popup, in user data permissions, select 'user_status' , same way in friends data permissions, select 'friend_status'. It will show you results on the same page.

Comment: Also on this URL - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fstatuses , you can change 'me' to the UserID you have, make sure this User must be your friend and it will display statuses you are looking for - but for testing only. How are you generating the token? PHP, iOS, Java, Android etc ?

Comment: Hey Reno, Thank you really very much for spending your time to reply. I highly appreciate. I followed above link, and it generated the new (and very long) access token. With that access token, I could get the status message. But then I logged out and i got the error that the token is invalid as the user got logged out. I'm generating the access token with PHP by https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRED&grant_type=client_credentials. How can I generate the new token because the above url is returning same token.

Comment: Simple Stuff - Open this URL on facebook - https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/my and then Go to 'Your apps' section at the bottom left. It will open up your apps. There you will see the Application which you have created and generated a token, Simply 'Remove' the application from your facebook 'your apps' section (not from your developers section) - OK ? Just delete the application from this URL only - https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/my and nowhere else. And Then hit the URL again via PHP, it will regenerate it by asking for permission. :)

Comment: As I said - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fstatuses is for testing purpose only. So, don't rely on this URL, its for testing only. :) You need to generate token using your PHP code.

Comment: Did that, still not working. I have understood that for the status message I need "user access token", while right now I'm using "app access token". I'm trying to find how to generate.